# numpy REJECTION before getting median or average of 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to write some functions to handle [FIT/FITS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS) (These are basically images) files. These files are common in astronomy.
In my case there is a bunch of calibration images and want to get average or median of all images.

so basically if my images (arrays) were:

```
ar1 = [[021, 654], [087, 065]]
ar2 = [[009, 097], [879, 009]]
ar1 = [[945, 008], [002, 007]]
```

resoult image (array) for median method will be:

```
armed = [[021, 097],[087, 009]]
```

and same thing for average

I found:

```
mainArray = [ar1, ar2,  ar3]
armed = numpy.median(mainArray, axis=0)
arave = numpy.average(mainArray, axis=0)
arsum = numpy.add(mainArray, axis=0)
arsub = numpy.subtract(mainArray, axis=0)
```

These are working good. But I want to do rejections too. For example before averaging the arrays I want to use min-max rejection.

There is four type of combination and three type of rejections.

combine types: sum, subtraction, median and average.
Rejection types: none, min-max, sigma Clip.

How to reject before combining arrays?

I just wrote a class to do min-max rejection. However it took forever to reject min-max of 10X(2048x2048) array. And actually, inArray is (10, 2048, 2048) shaped but in return I'm getting (2048, 2048, 8). The 8 means min-max rejected. But reverse. :(

```
def minmaxrej(self, inArray, verb=False):
    """
    Returns all images minmax rejected.

    @param inArray: All arrays to reject minmax. It'll return a reverced array.
    @type inArray: numpy.array
    @param verb: Get information while operation (Optional, False by default).
    @type verb: boolean
    @return: numpy.array
    """
    if type(inArray) == numpy.ndarray:
        if len(inArray.shape) == 3:
            if inArray.shape[0] > 2:
                poi = []
                ln = []
                lst = []

                for i in xrange(inArray.shape[1]):
                    for u in xrange(inArray.shape[2]):
                        for k in xrange(inArray.shape[0]):
                            poi.append(inArray[k][i][u])
                        poi = numpy.sort(poi)[1:-1]
                        ln.append(poi)
                        poi = []
                    lst.append(ln)
                    ln = []
                lst = numpy.asarray(lst)
                if verb:
                    print "'minmaxrej' done."
                return lst

            else:
                if verb:
                    print "Min-Max rejection requires at least 3 arrays. Got %s." %(inArray.shape[0])
        else:
            if verb:
                print "Wrong array shape. Expected array type: %s" %(inArray.shape)
    else:
        if verb:
            print "Unexpected input type for input arrays.\nArray expected.\nReceived %s" %(type(inArray))
```

After this I can get median, mean, average, sum etc of this array. But it took too long. I need more effective and fast way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

New:

```
import numpy as np
ar1 = [[21, 654], [87, 65]] # this is a nested list and becomes matrix-like if np.array(ar1) is called
ar2 = [[9, 97], [879, 9]]
ar3 = [[945, 8], [2, 7]]
all_arr = np.array([ar1,ar2,ar3]) # This is a list of 'matrices' / np.arrays with shape (m,n)
matrix = all_arr.reshape((3,4)).T # This is getting rid of the list so that we now have an array of shape (#arrs, #len(each arr))
```

I use transpose so that every image (e.g. ar1) is a column and every row is a pixel

```
Output:
array([[ 21,   9, 945],
       [654,  97,   8],
       [ 87, 879,   2],
       [ 65,   9,   7]])
```

You can then define whatever filter you'd like

```
def is_min_or_max(X):
    return (X == np.max(X))|(X == np.min(X))
```

to then filter our 'matrix' you can apply this 'filter' to every row / pixel with something like
`map(is_min_or_max, matrix)`. This would give you:

```
Output:
[array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool),
 array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool),
 array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool),
 array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)]
```

If I understand you correctly you want to discard a picture (arr1) if any of the filters apply to any of the pixels in that image, that means
discard the picture if any of the values in the array is true. Then You get your matrix by:

```
matrix[:, np.invert(map(any, map(is_min_or_max, matrix)))]

Output: array([], shape=(4L, 0L), dtype=int32)
```

Which is empty in this case since every image has an excluding factor.
If it weren't empty you could then use the `np.mean()` etc. functions over the axis of your choosing (pixels or images) as you've done already.

---

OLD:

In your case I'd probably work with numpy matrices as they support easy slicing and boolean filtering on either axis.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

ar1 = [[21, 654], [87, 65]]
ar2 = [[9, 97], [879, 9]]
ar3 = [[945, 8], [2, 7]]

ar1 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ar1))
ar2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ar2))
ar3 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ar3))
mat = np.matrix([ar1,ar2,ar3])
armed = np.median(mat,0)
arave = np.mean(mat,0)
```

...and so on. The rejection can then be done to the matrix by slicing like

```
mat[mat[:,0] < np.max(mat[:,0])]
```

for the first column. The slicing can be a boolean matrix as well, so you can combine the conditions for all columns

Thanks

Comment: ittertools just converted my (2048,2048) shaped array to (4194304,).
I just wanted getting median of all 1stx1st, 1stx2end, 1stx3rd ... 2047thx2047th and 2048thx2048th values.

Comment: In your example you're using three nested lists (ar1,ar2, and ar1 again) don't you then want the median of all the first entries in the first list of all three lists (ar1,ar2,ar3)? Because to create a matrix and vectorise (really speed it up) this, the nested lists first need to become flat lists to use then as a "row" in the matrix...that's what itertools.chain should do for you.

Comment: Actually it works only if you reshape your matrix after the process. Because after this process you'll have a vector not matrix. reshaping is not problem. The problem is:

I'm working with image data. So I'll have 10 images and these are calibration images. I want to get average of all pixels, like average of all 1st pixels will be my first pixel, average of all second pixels will be my second pixel...
By saying rejection I meant min-max rejection for process above. When I'll get average of all first pixels I want to do min-max rejection. And at least I'll have an image.

Comment: Updated again. Hope I could finally help you out.